# How to check a cell that contains the specific number in any order on google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to ask how to do this on google sheets. I have spend days to find a tutorial how but I couldn't have the right answer or keyword to search for.

I have a list of ID Number on A and on B declare a set of number, I want my formula to check the cells of A if it contains set of number from B in any order.

Example:

A2 has ID number of 120 and my B2 search for 021, as long as the number in B has same number in A whether order or in order it will reply YES on C2.

Please help, thank you!

[Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0hNy.png)

Comment: Can you show what research you did so far? Do you have a code/formula you're working on?

Comment: I don't have a working formula but I tried (LOOKUP,VLOOKUP,HLOOKUP,QUERY,SEARCH,FIND,REGEXMATCH,MATCH) but they only look for the exact order of the number. I don't know how to write script, I am only looking for basic formula if there is that I don't know of the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

As custom function:

```
function IMPORTJSON(VS) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet()
  const vs = VS.filter(r => r[0] && r[1]);//both must have values
  const mA = [];//match array
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let A = r[0].toString().split("").sort((a,b) => a - b).join("");
    let B = r[1].toString().split("").sort((a,b) => a - b).join("");
    if(A == B) {
      mA.push(`A: ${r[0]} B: ${r[1]} row: ${i+2}`)
    }
  });
  return mA.join("\n");
}
```

Usage:

=IMPORTJSON("A2:B")

Comment: Thank you for the reply, sadly I don't know how to make this work. I already watch tutorials how to put this on google sheet tools > script editor. Rename the script to ImportJSON but when I try to type =ImportJSON , it didn't show up on my sheet.

Comment: You need to be clear that a function is going to be used as a custom function when you asked for one.  In google apps script a custom function is one that is used as a user created formula.  There are restriction and requirements that apply your should [read them](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: Hi, the function works now after reading the link I understand how to do it. The code works but it reply on the cell "A: 120 B: 021 row: 2" , I wanted to have it reply YES or NO. I tried this formula but it doesnt work. "=IF(IMPORTJSON(G2:H2),I2/6*100)", I need it to check first if it has the same content then if YES, I want it to check the value of cell id I2 then divide it and multiply. Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome to make any changes required.

Comment: The current function returns a string not a boolean.  I don't use formula's much but you could try something like this `=IF(LEN(IMPORTJSON(A2:B2))>0,"Yes","No")`

Comment: Wow, now this is what I am looking for. It works and also I can do a math on it. Thank you so much and thank you for your time replying me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an arguably more direct [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

First, open a bound script by selecting `Tools > Script editor`, and copy the following function to the script (check inline comments):

```
function SAME_NUMBERS(cell1, cell2) {
  if (cell1 && cell2) { // Check that both parameters are not empty
    const ordered1 = cell1.toString().split("").sort().join(""); // Sort value 1
    const ordered2 = cell2.toString().split("").sort().join(""); // Sort value 2
    return ordered1 === ordered2 ? "YES" : "NO"; // Check that both values match
  }
}
```

Once it is defined, you can use this function the same you would any sheets built-in function. This function accepts two parameters, for the cells in column A and B:

[image]

Or, alternatively, passing the full range in a parameter and calling the function once:

```
function SAME_NUMBERS_ARRAY(values) {
  return values.map(row => {
    if (row[0] && row[1]) {
      const ordered1 = row[0].toString().split("").sort().join("");
      const ordered2 = row[1].toString().split("").sort().join("");
      return ordered1 === ordered2 ? "YES" : "NO";      
    }
  })
}
```

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply this one works only if the number is reversed. Like A2 is 120, B2 is 021, but if I put 210 in B2 it reply FALSE. I am looking for that should work as long as the contain number is there in ID whatever the order is. 120,102,210,201,012,021 should be TRUE if the ID is 120.

Comment: @TessieGregorio My bad, I misunderstood your question before. I just updated my answer with an arguably more direct way to do this with a custom function (either calling the function in each row or just once for the full range).